# changing only changed property of an array or object comparing to next array or object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reactive-programming

I have two array **a** and **b** , array **a** is reactive array which contain reactive objects , My array is bind with my UI(i.e simply looping over

element and displaying data) when I update any objects of array or when I change any property of objects at array then my view layer automatically updates. Now I am trying to create function which receive my both array and which update only updated or changed property of array **a** without touching unupdated data of array or unupdated property of object which is inside array **a** looking at array **b**.

I am not using any JavaScript liberty or framework. I had problem while deep cloning array **b** and placing cloned array in variable **a** I tried cloning but my problem was unsolved. Please help me.

```js
var a = [
   {name:'mina' , age:18 , subject:'computer'}, //
   {name:'japan'}
];

var b = [
  {name:'mina pandey' , age:19 , subject:'computer'},
  {name:'okkk' , aws:false}
]

function LogicalUpdator(updating , newData) {     
   newData.forEach((el , index) => {
      if(typeof el == 'object'){
         var keys = Object.keys(el);
         keys.forEach(function(a){
           if(updating[index][a] !== el[a]){
             updating[index][a] = el[a];
           }
         })
      }else if(Array.isArray(el)){
         el.forEach(function(a){
           if(updating[index] !== el[a]){
             updating[index] = el[a];
           }
         })
      }else if(typeof el == 'string'){

      }
   });
}

BestUpdate(a , b);
```

I wrote more then 10 times but I couldn't solve it. I tried my best please help me.

Detail problem according to code:-

From array a[0] `name` should be converted to `mina pandey` looking at `b[0].name` likewise `a[0].age` should be converted to `19` looking at array **b** `b[0].age` but `a[0].subject` i.e `computer` should not be changed because `a[0].subject == b[0].subject`, similarly `a[1].name` i.e `japan` should be changed to `b[1].name` i.e`okkk` and new property `aws` should be added to `a[1]` because `b[1]` has new property `aws` looking at `a` similarly when new data `(i.e object, array, number, boolen , string)` is added on array **b** then same data should be added to array **a** same in removed case when any data is removed from array **b** then same data should be removed from array **a** as well.

Please don't question me why aren't you directly updating array **a** (Reactive array) , There are some deep and genuine reasons which is related to my project which contain this small problem. Sorry I cannot explain about my project on stack overflow or any public sites.

Please Help Me, I felt very difficult to solve this problem because I am just a learner I don't have deep knowledge to deal with such type of complex problem.